# What After svnadmin load finish?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svn-server

I am Transferring repository one different server to other server, Means old server has different url of trunk and the new one that I have to create new repository and trunk.

I get `svnadmin dump` files from old server and load to new server by this to command

1. I create new repository by `svnadmin create SvnNew` the `SvnNew` is my new repository.
2. Now I load svn dump file in to new repository by `svnadmin load SvnNew < xyz.dump`

Now what do after finish ?

How to create trunk ? 
How to create svn trunk url ? 
How to set svn user ?

Please Help me I am in big trouble

Answer (score 3):

There should be no need to create trunk because that's a directory *inside* your repository, and that will be handled by the dump/load cycle.

Can't exactly say what more you need to do after the load because you haven't detailed what else you've done with your repository and server setup. Fortunately for you, [the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) explains how to move your repository to a new server.

Determining the URL and creating users will depend upon what Subversion server package you're using (CollabNet, VisualSVN Server, etc.) if any and how you handle user credentials/authorization (LDAP authentication? SSH access?). These are all things you *should have* figured out *before* you started moving things around, even going so far as to stand up a test server to make sure you can do it all successfully before messing around with production.

For now, roll back to your old server and practice the migration in a non-production environment so that you don't disrupt users before you're really ready to make the switch.